# Plugin not triggering while placing order

Tags: plugin, magento2.2.4

I am creating a plugin for Quotemanagement (placeOrder) with after method, but some reason it’s not triggering. I try with die but no luck

Please help, I am using Magento 2.2.6

Here is my code

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class QuoteManagement {
protected $logger;
protected $quoteFactory;
protected $orderFactory;

public function __construct(\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
                            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
                            \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->quoteFactory =   $quoteFactory;
    $this->orderFactory =   $orderFactory;

}
/**
 * Before order success action
 */
public function afterPlaceOrder($quoteManagement, $result){
    $order  =   $this->orderFactory->create()->load($result);
    $quote  =   $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());
    $addvalue =   $quote->getAdcodeValue();
    $order->setAdcodeValue($quote->getAdcodeValue());
    $order->save();

    return $result;
}
```

}

also here is my di.xml file

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action">
    <plugin name="Module_Name::urlstringcheck" type="Vendor\modulename\Plugin\ActionUrlValueCheck" />
</type>
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement">
    <plugin name="Module_Name::checktheorder" type="Vendor\modulename\Plugin\QuoteManagement" />
</type>
```

Comment: what is the location of di.xml file?

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar  - /etc/frontend/di.xml also i tried in  /etc/di.xml

Comment: Please keep your module name's first character in upper case

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar - My module name start with upper case

Answer (score 0):

Using checkout_submit_all_after event to handle after checkout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="Vendor_Module::checkout_after_do_something" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SaveOrderAfterSubmitObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

The Observer

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class SaveOrderAfterSubmitObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        /* @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        // Do crazy stuff here

        return $this;

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried observer first and it's not working that's why i try to write plugin

Answer (score 0):

Update your method with below code.

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement">
    <plugin name="Module_Name::checktheorder" type="Vendor\Modulename\Plugin\QuoteManagement" />
</type>
```

**QuoteManagement.php**

```
public function afterPlaceOrder(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement, $result){
    $order  =   $this->orderFactory->create()->load($result);
    $quote  =   $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());
    $addvalue =   $quote->getAdcodeValue();
    $order->setAdcodeValue($quote->getAdcodeValue());
    $order->save();

    return $result;
}
```

I hope it will work for you

Comment: Thanks for the help and I tried your method and not working but I have two plugin and is this cause the  issue?

Comment: I think thats not any issue. Make sure your di.xml is in global scope.

Comment: - you mean etc/di.xml correct, if yes i did that also. i am using M2.2.6

Comment: Everything is fine. I hope you already verified that your module is enabled.

Comment: yes module is enabled